# C++ cout won't work inside for and if?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, cout

I have those two pieces of code as my home assignment. The code looks all fine to me, but it won't print out what I want, no matter what. In fact, the console output remains completely empty.

The first program is supposed to print out all numbers that fulfil the `ladna()` function requirements and are between `1` and `a`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a;
int i = 1;

bool ladna(int a)
    {
    if((((a>>4)*5+a*2)%3)==1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }

int main()
{

    cerr << "Podaj liczbe: " << endl;
    cin >> a;

    while (i <= a){

        if (ladna(a)){
            cout << i << " ";
        }

        i++;

    }

}
```

the `ladna()` function is premade and I have to use it as is.

I tried changing `while` into `do...while` and `for`, didn't help. Doesn;t work with `cerr` either.

The second code has to print out all the natural divisors of number `a`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int a;

    cerr << "Podaj liczbe" << endl;
    cin >> a;

    for (int i = 0; i >= a; i++){

        if (a % i == 0){

            cout << i << endl;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Doesn't work either.

To me it looks like both pieces of code have the same issue, because they are written in the same way, based on the same principle, and the error is the same. Hence my assumption, that the cause is the same as well.

Unfortunately, for the love of me, I simply can't see what said error is...

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: `if( condition ) return true; else return false;` is equal to `return condition;`

Comment: You are best off to step through your code with the debugger, and check if the `cout` statements are executed at all.

Comment: Example of input would be also nice.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i >= a; i++){` It would either not execute at all, or will lead to signed overflow, i.e. UB.

Answer (score 1):

For the first code:

I think you should call ladna function with i, like `ladna(i)`

For the second code:

In `for` it should be `i<=a`

'%' is the modulo operator, during the execution of `(a%i)` you divide a with i and take the remainder, since i start with zero you will get "Floating point exception (core dumped)" due to division by zero. So, `for` should start with 1. This should work:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++){

    if (a%i == 0){

        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```